# Notify view controllers from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Segment Control and a Container in a ViewController. In the container is a PageViewController. If you click on one of the items from the Segment Control the value "active" of the table "user" is changed.(sqlite)
table "user":

```
username text, active bool
user1, false
user2,true
```

So if you click on user1 in the Segment Control the table would change to

```
username text, active bool
    user1, true
    user2,false
```

Is there a way that all the ViewControllers in the PageViewController  recognize the change in the database and reload their data with the new user. If this is not possible how would be the best way to do this?

Kindly regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood right, you want the notify some view controllers when you changed the segmented controls value in another view controller.

In this case, you can use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/).

`NsNotificationCenter` sends notifications to its observers. And you can make it do something when the observer receives the notification.

Example:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(aMethod(_:)), name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)

func aMethod(notification: NSNotification){
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you thats working! but I got an error. I have placed a label on one of the views in the PageViewControler. So when I click on the SegmentControl the funcion "aMethod" get called in the viewcontroller but I get the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I want to change the text of the label in the viewcontroler. Why is the label = nil? I changed the text of the label in the viewDidLoad() function without problems.

Comment: It must be because that view controller is not allocated in memory yet. I mean its viewDidLoad didn't get called or it's deallocated in the memory afterwards. The IBOulets are alive as long as their view controller are alive.

Comment: Ok. So when I call self.viewDidLoad() in the "aMethod" and call the the function "reloadLabel" in the viewDidLoad(), the label is still nil. How is the right way to reload the data in the ViewController?

Comment: No you get it wrong. You shouldn't call viewDidLoad manually. What I tried to say is that label's view controller should be alive in the application.

Comment: So it should be alive in the application but it isn't. So how is this possible. The ViewController with the label is displayed on the screen when I click on the Segment Control.

Comment: Then maybe the label isn't wired to the label in the view controller in the storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120891/discussion-between-kenan-karakecili-and-reasyeasypeasy).